# How to use the response in fetch request React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new in react native world and (JS).
I want to send **phone number** and **password** to the server to login. I can send data and receive response, however, I don't how I should handle response. I have a function called **_response_recognizer**. But it is not working. Even **setStat**. All of the tutorials only say how to connect to server and how fetch data from it. What is the best approach to use response in my login form. If it's status is 200 I want to navigate another screen, else I want to toast a message.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput, Button
} from 'react-native';

export default class LoginForm extends Component<{}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._onLogInPressed = this._onLogInPressed.bind(this);
        this._response_recognizer = this._response_recognizer.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            phone_number: '',
            password: '',
            data: {}
        };
    }
    _response_recognizer(data: string ){

    }

    _onLogInPressed = () => {

        var data = {
            'phone_number': this.state.phone_number,
            'password': this.state.password
        }


        fetch("http://192.168.1.12:5000/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            body:  JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(function(response){
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(data){
                console.log(data)
            this._response_recognizer(data)
            }) .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error" + error);
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.flow}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>phone number:</Text>
                <TextInput keyboardType='numeric'
                           style={styles.input}
                           ref="phone_number"
                           onChangeText={(phone_number) => this.setState({phone_number})}
                           maxLengt={11}
                           value={this.state.phone_number}
                />
                <Text style={styles.text}>password:</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.input} secureTextEntry={true} ref="password"
                           onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                           value={this.state.password}/>
                <Button style={styles.button} onPress={this._onLogInPressed} title='login'/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things.

Your `_response_recognizer` function is requesting `data: string` but you are returning an json `object`:

```
.then(function(response){
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data){
  console.log(data)
  this._response_recognizer(data)
})
```

Change that to `data: object`.

Secondly, you are using **function declarations** (`function(){}`) in your `.then`'s. Without directly binding `this`, you lose the scope your `Class` functions. Change them to an **arrow function** (`() => {}`) to fix the scope issue:

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
  this._response_recognizer(data)
})
```

You can also opt to remove one of the `.then` operations:

```
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response.json())
  this._response_recognizer(response.json())
})
```

✌

Answer (score 0):

check this ...

i hope this code helps you

```
    export default class LoginForm extends Component<{}> {
    state = {
           data:[],

        }


     _onLogInPressed = () => {

          fetch('http://192.168.1.12:5000/login',{
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                  'Accept':'application/json',
                  'Content-Type':'application/json',
                },
                body:JSON.stringify({
                 'phone_number': this.state.phone_number,
                'password': this.state.password
                })
              })
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((res) =>{
                if(res.success === true){
              alert(res.response);
         let datadata = res.data;
           this.setState({data:datadata})

                } else {
                  alert(res.response);
                }
              })
              .done();


            };

//// Render function
////Rander function


    }
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain how this answers the question?

Comment: this answer help to handle json response coming from server .
in this i setState server response and use any where in class according to condition